# 2 Djangos 1 Server

Tags: django, apache

I have Deployed several projects of mine onto my new server. What seems to be happening is I can view one project fine, but once I go to the next one, the settings for the previous project are still being used.

For example, jacobvalenta.net and dev.pawndaddy.org are both projects on the server, flipping between the two can result in the settings getting mixed up.

```
SGIPythonPath /home/projects/pawndaddy:/home/projects/jacobvalenta:/home/projects/sailcast:/home/projects/tryfecta:/home/projects/midiscribe

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName jacobvalenta.net
        ServerAlias *.jacobvalenta.net

        DocumentRoot /home/projects/jacobvalenta
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/projects/jacobvalenta/jacobvalenta/wsgi.py

        <Directory /home/projects/jacobvalenta/jacobvalenta>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Order deny,allow
                        Allow from all
                </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName sailcast.org
        ServerAlias *.sailcast.org

        DocumentRoot /home/projects/sailcast
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/projects/sailcast/sailcast/wsgi.py

        <Directory /home/projects/sailcast/sailcast>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Order deny,allow
                        Allow from all
                </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName pawndaddy.org
        ServerAlias *.pawndaddy.org

        DocumentRoot /home/projects/pawndaddy/
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/projects/pawndaddy/pawndaddy/wsgi.py

        <Directory /home/projects/pawndaddy/pawndaddy>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Order deny,allow
                        Allow from all
                </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: OK. Now, are you going to post any details of your setup so that we can perhaps help you debug it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman There is the configuration. Everything else is the default apache settings

Comment: "flipping between the two can result in the settings getting mixed up." Please be more specific on *flipping* and *getting mixed up*. In case you see data appearing crossing the virtual hosted sites, you should make sure you're using different databases and filesystem locations of the Django installations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have read the files a little bit more!

Within wsgi.py, the comments say:

```
# We defer to a DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE already in the environment. This breaks
# if running multiple sites in the same mod_wsgi process. To fix this, use
# mod_wsgi daemon mode with each site in its own daemon process, or use
# os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "project.settings"
```

so just remove the line about setting the default environment, and all should be good.